# function scope interfere with my function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can run my functions **Off()** and **Live()** without removal function scope **.ready()**?

```
<form id="1" name="first-form">
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit 1" onClick="Off();">
    </p>
</form>

<form id="2" name="second-form">
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit 2" onClick="Live();">
    </p>
</form>
```

My js code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Off(){
        alert('off');
    }

    function Live(){
        alert('live');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are those 2 functions in the DOM ready anyway?

Comment: What's the problem with putting the function outside of the `.ready`?

Comment: I won't recommend, You can use `window.Off = function ()` instead of `function Off()` better move your function outside `.ready`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commenters have made the point that you should just move the functions out of the scope. But if that's not possible you could add the functions to an object (so you don't have a huge number of variables polluting the global scope) and export that; then just change the name of the functions that the click events call.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    window.module = {
      Off: function () {
        alert('off');
      },
      Live: function () {
        alert('live');
      }
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Submit 1" onClick="module.Off();" />
<input type="button" value="Submit 2" onClick="module.Live();" />
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dmve068k/7/)

Seriously, this is far from the optimal solution, but it does answer your question I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your handler in html then your funtion need to be global, try removing ready function:

```
function Off(){
    alert('off');
}

function Live(){
    alert('live');
}
```